# Rounding off decimals in Django

Tags: django, numbers, rounding, decimal

I want to round off my decimal values as below:

7,715.625 becomes 7,716

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Note: the template filter "intcomma" used in the solution is part of django.contrib.humanize, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you don't care about the commas, then [`floatformat`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) will do the job:

```
{{ value|floatformat:"0" }}
```

If you do care about commas, you want:

```
{{ value|floatformat:"0"|intcomma }}
```

(Hat tip to Stephen for pointing me at `intcomma`!)

Comment: floatformat will give me one decimal place...I tried this first.  I need to have my value without any decimal place

Comment: @Dominic {{ value|floatformat:"0"|intcomma }} will add the thousands separator (it's part of humanize)

Comment: @Stephen - thanks - I was actually looking for that exact filter today, and couldn't find it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

To use `intcomma` filter, you should add `django.contrib.humanize` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and `{% load humanize %}` in a template.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the below on django, the argument "0" rounds it to exclude decimal places, but you can change it.

```
number = 7715.625
rounded_number = round(number,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the round function and there is no need to specify the digits either. By default it returns an integer from the given float value.

```
number = 7715.615
rounded_number = round(number)
```